# How to write JSON Reads for models without a matching constructor signature?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have the following JSON object:

```
{"values": "123,456,789"}
```

I'd like to convert this JSON object to an instance of class `Foo` with the following signature, using the JSON library of the play framework:

```
case class Foo(value1: Double, value2: Double, value3: Double)
```

In the [documentation about JSON combinators](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonCombinators), there are just examples for conversions where the constructor signature of the class matches the extracted JSON values. If I had such a case, I'd have to write the following Reads function:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

implicit val fooReads: Reads[Foo] = (
  (JsPath \ "values").read[String]
)(Foo.apply _)
```

However, first I have to split the string `"123,456,789"`to three separate strings, and convert each of them to `Double` values before I can create an instance of class `Foo`. How can I do this with JSON combinators? I was not able to find examples for that. Trying to pass in a function literal as an argument does not work:

```
// this does not work
implicit val fooReads: Reads[Foo] = (
  (JsPath \ "values").read[String]
)((values: String) => {
  val Array(value1, value2, value3) = values.split(",").map(_.toDouble)
  Foo(value1, value2, value3)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is getting confused and thinks you are passing your function as the (usually implicit) parameter to the `read` method. You can get around this by explicitly using `Reads.map` instead of `ApplicationOps.apply`:

```
implicit val fooReads: Reads[Foo] = {
  (JsPath \ "values").read[String] map { values =>
    val Array(value1, value2, value3) = values.split(",").map(_.toDouble)
    Foo(value1, value2, value3)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can overload the companion object's `apply` method which does not require any changes to your implicit read code. Instead, the logic to turn the string into a set of values would be contained in `apply`.

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Foo(value1: Double, value2: Double, value3: Double)

object Foo {
    def apply(values: String) = {
        values =>
            val Array(value1, value2, value3) = values.split(",").map(_.toDouble)
            Foo(value1, value2, value3)
    }

    implicit val fooReads: Reads[Foo] = (
      (JsPath \ "values").read[String]
    )(Foo.apply _)
}
```